# Are username and password visible while connecting to HTTP Proxy

Tags: proxy

In a lot of cases we use `HTTP Proxy`.
For authentication to this proxy we use `IP`:`PORT` and `username` and `password`.
When we use proxy settings in browser, browser initiates CONNECT method to Proxy server and browser sends `"Proxy-Authorization: Basic ..."` - where `...` - is just `base64` encoded `username` and `password`.

So these `username` and `password` are still visible to my Internet provider and anyone in the public network? Anyone can record TCP dump and use my Proxy?

If yes - Is there any way to hide `username` and `password`?

Comment: Yep. You'd need your proxy to support HTTPS.

Comment: See for detailed answers https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23561/authenticating-a-proxy-server-over-https